# Export to .dbf and .mdb

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, ms-access, dbf

A have a number of shapefiles and I want to export their attribute table to .dbf and .mdb (Microsoft Access file). How can I do this with ArcGis or with any other tools?

Notice that I want to keep their actual field names.

E.x. When I use "table to table" tool the "FID" field change to "OID". I do not want this to happen.

Comment: The FID column doesn't really exist.  It's a phantom field to represent the row number (zero-based) in a shape file.  OID is the equivalent in Access.  You can't prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with this [software](https://www.safe.com/convert/shp-to-mdb/)?

You can try with the free trial version

Comment: Please consider expanding this answer with more information about the software, since the answer in its current state is likely to suffer from link rot.

Comment: No I didn't try this software. I will give it a change. Have you try this by your self? It seems very promising software, but I was thinging something like a python script.

Comment: I run the translation tool in FME but in the results I didn't get the field with FID at all, neither as FID nor as any other name. For my analysis this field is crucial. Any other suggestions anyone?